# Fail to convert base64 string when using TryFromBase64String

Tags: c#, guid

I receive a Guid as a base64 string. By using the `Convert.FromBase64String(b64)`, the conversion is working well, then I try to use the `Convert.TryFromBase64String(b64)` but in that case, the method return false and my byte array stays empty

```cs
var dataString = "kADs1tnSQ+2ehpdtUAK/Jg==";
// output: d6ec0090-d2d9-ed43-9e86-976d5002bf26
Console.WriteLine(new Guid(Convert.FromBase64String(dataString)));

Span<byte> bytes = new();
bool success = Convert.TryFromBase64String(dataString, bytes, out int _);

// output: False, then FormatException
Console.WriteLine(success);
Console.WriteLine(new Guid(success ? bytes : Convert.FromHexString(dataString)));
```

I guess my problem is with the initialization of the `Span`, because if I use `new byte[16]`, it is working, but is it safe to write it using a fixed size of 16?

Comment: In what sense "is it safe"? If the buffer will be too small it will return false as a result.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-8.0): "A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes)" so yes, I'd say it's safe to use a fixed size of 16.

Comment: Ok, by is it safe, I mean if exist a way to use the span without specify the length, let the TryFromBase64String use the correct size alone

Comment: Unless there is something else you're not disclosing to us. Using a Span here is redundant. Spans are intended to be used where you would otherwise be copying slices of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide `bytes` with allocated space, e.g.

```
// 16 bytes to store parsed GUID
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];

bool success = Convert.TryFromBase64String(dataString, bytes, out int _);
```

Similar, if you want to use `Span`:

```
// Span of the array which allocates 16 bytes to store GUID
var bytes = new byte[16].AsSpan();

bool success = Convert.TryFromBase64String(dataString, bytes, out int _);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `Span` and allocate space to write the processed result. For example:

```
Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[16];
bool success = Convert.TryFromBase64String(dataString, bytes, out int bytesWritten);
```

Otherwise you are creating an empty one and `Convert.TryFromBase64String` will write zero bytes into it (it can't and won't allocate any space for the passed one).

From [the `Convert.TryFromBase64String` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tryfrombase64string?view=net-8.0) (emphasis mine):

> `bytes` `Span<Byte>`
> The span in which to write the converted 8-bit unsigned integers. **When this method returns false, either the span remains unmodified or contains an incomplete conversion of `s`, up to the last valid character**.

So you will get `success` as `False` on actually valid base64 string which you will then try to process as a hex one.